# Comparing probabilites of error for differenct 'k' in a k-NN Classifier

Tags: classification, error, k-nearest-neighbour, pattern-recognition

Here is a question that I'm stuck with:

> Consider two classes $w_1$, $w_2$ in the two-dimensional space. The data from
> class $w_1$ are uniformly distributed inside a circle of radius $r$. The data of
> class $w_2$ are also uniformly distributed inside another circle of radius $r$. The
> distance between the centers of the circles is greater than $4r$. Let $N$ be
> the number of the available training samples. Show that the probability
> of error of the 1-NN classifier is always smaller than that of the kNN, for
> any $k \geq 3$.

(if it helps, this is question 2.34 from [Pattern Recognition by Theodoridis and Koutroumbas](https://www.elsevier.com/books/pattern-recognition/koutroumbas/978-1-59749-272-0))

I would appreciate if anyone can help me solve it.